# Writing equations in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I'm working on a simple equation: y = (1/1+2x) - ((1-x)/(1+x)). In matlab I wrote it like this: (1./(1+(2.*x)))-((1-x)./(1+x)); since my x's are in a range I have to use (.) operator. My equation however is not plotting the graph as I would expect it. It is a parabola with a minimum critical point at around x = 50 which doesn't make sense. This leads me to believe I have a syntax error. If someone could help it would be much appreciated!

Here is my current code:

```
f = @(x) (1./(1+(2.*x)))-((1-x)./(1+x));
h =1*exp(-10);
x = (-1*exp(-6)):h:(1*exp(-6));
y = f(x);
plot(y)
```

Comment: Please share your code!

Comment: Completely forgot about that! I just edited it :)

Comment: +1 for Try Hard. You didn't give `plot` xvalues so it is plotted on a default `x` for `x=1:length(y)`.

Comment: Quick validation to check whether the proposed answer does what you expect is to see whether you expect a peak around `x(50)`. (That is basically what you see in the plot now).

Comment: Adding the plot(x,y) helped but the graph is still not what I am expecting. The plot shows the Y values approaching 1 as x goes to +/- infinity which they should be going to infinity as well unless I messed up this graph: https://www.google.com/#q=graph+(1%2F1%2B2x)-((1-x)%2F(1%2Bx))&safe=off

Comment: The function, as you have written it, approaches 1 as x goes to +/- infinity. You forgot a parentheses in google. Very easy to verify with pen and paper if you substitute x by +/- inf

Comment: I hate making stupid mistakes like that, Thank you everyone!

Comment: @rsayles3: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but it looks to me that you might not know that `exp(x)` is the natural exponent and not `10^x`?

Comment: What I want is 1e^-6, isn't that how I represent it?

Comment: 1e^-6 is simply `1e-6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are plotting your `f(x)` with default x-axis, from `1:numel(y)`.

To get the correct result try:

```
plot(x,f(x))
```

or

```
plot(x,y)
```